# Angular fakeAsync does not work with Rx asap scheduler

Tags: angular, testing, rxjs

I have a mock service that returns the following observable.

```
const mock = {
  get() {
    return of([{id: 3}], asap);
  }
};

 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestComponent ],
      providers: [{provide: TestService, useValue: mock}]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

In my component I am subscribing to the service result and ngFor them:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.TestService.get().subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
    });
  }
```

I'm trying to use the `fakeAsync` with `tick()` but that does not work. The test is failed.

```
   it('should work...', fakeAsync(() => {
     fixture.detectChanges();
     tick();
     fixture.detectChanges();
     expect(element.querySelectorAll('.list-item').length).toEqual(1);
  }));
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: put tick(1) instead of just tick()

Comment: can you explain why, please?

Comment: not works anyway

Comment: Let me run this at my end and get back to u.